# Как задействовать переменные подкласса

Tags: java, ооп

Есть суперкласс Flower, он имеет два подкласса Rose и Gvozdika.
Как задействовать переменные подкласса в цикле, который приведен ниже (в данный момент он выводит нули):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flower[] byket=new Flower[4];
    byket[0] = new Rosa();
    byket[1] = new Gvozdika();
    byket[2] = new Gvozdika();
    byket[3] = new Rosa();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < byket.length;i++) {
       sum = byket[i].cena + sum;
       Flower.cout++;
       System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Классы:

```
public class Flower {
  private String proizv;
  int srok;
  public   int cena;
  static int cout;
}

public class Rosa extends Flower {
  int cena=100;
}

public class Gvozdika extends Flower {
  int cena=20;
}
```

Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: пожалуйста, отформатируйте код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `Flower` и `Rose`, то не `Gvozdika`, а `Carnation`.

```
public class Rosa extends Flower {
  public Rosa() {
    cena = 100;
  }
}

public class Carnation extends Flower {
  public Carnation() {
    cena = 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам что заметили! Постепенно избавляюсь от такого написания :)